# Using csv training data in tensorflow RNN

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I am fairly new to tensorflow, and did the obligatory MNIST tutorial successfully.

I am trying to train a simple RNN with a set of CSV data. The data is 33 features and a binary output variable at the end (so 34 columns).

I have implemented a csv reader that reads in one line at a time. I am trying to read that line and pass it into my tensorflow graph. I feel like the "TensorFlow-way" is starting to become more clear but also that there are some fundamental pieces missing - particularly as it relates to streaming data into your model.

I have included an example of what I'm doing below. Most of the code has been stripped for clarity, but the important part remains:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import datapipe as datapipe

learning_rate = 0.001
n_features    = 33
n_hidden      = 100 # number of features in the hidden layer - I just made this up
n_classes     = 2 # 0 or 1 - a binary classification

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1, n_features])
y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_classes])

transform = tf.transpose(x)

with tf.session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

  coord   = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  datapipe = datapipe.Datapipe(filename='training.csv', features=33, epochs=100)

  while not coord.should_stop():
    nextline = datapipe.nextline()

    # I basically want to run "transform" with the nextline of the csv file
    stuff = sess.run(transform, feed_dict={ x: nextline })
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

And `datapipe` is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Datapipe:
    def __init__(self, filename=None, features=None, epochs=100):
        self.filename = filename
        self.features = features
        self.epochs   = epochs

        self.defaults = []
        for i in range(self.features):
            self.defaults.append([]) # require all fields to be present

    def nextline(self):
        file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([self.filename], num_epochs=self.epochs, shuffle=False)
        reader = tf.TextLineReader()

        key, csv_str = reader.read(file_queue)
        return tf.pack(tf.decode_csv(csv_str, record_defaults=self.defaults))
```

When I run this example, I get the error:

`TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.`

Thank you for all your help!

**EDIT**

My question is essentially: *How can I feed file data (e.g. csv) into a tensorflow model?* (the tutorials weren't helpful)

**EDIT 12/09/2016**

Based on the answer by Sergii, I am doing this now:

```
with open('../data/training2.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        arr = np.array(line)

        x = arr[0:len(arr)-1:1]
        y = arr[len(arr)-1:len(arr):1]

        sess.run(transform, feed_dict={ x: x, y: y })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if placeholder and reading data from file are complementary or exclusive, but `nextline` variable already is a tensor with 33 values from your CSV (therefore an example of X).

I think you can do:

```
transform = tf.transpose(nextline)
stuff = sess.run(transform)
println(stuff)
```

you will see `stuff` as an array that is the first line in the CSV.

If you repeat `sess.run(transform)`, you will get the next line and so forth.

To use batch, you can do something like:

```
X_batch = tf.train.batch(nextline, batch_size=100)
stuff = sess.run(X_batch)
println(stuff)
```

Each time you call `sess.run(X_batch)` you will fetch 100 lines of your CSV.

Answer (score 1):

`Tensor` objects can not be values of `feed_dict`, it takes actual values, like `numpy` arrays, strings, etc as an input. See for example [this issue.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3389)

Try to modify `nextline` method and do not create a `Tensor` there but transform your csv strings into numpy arrays instead.

Comment: Sounds good. I wanted to use the native tensorflow csv reader methods because I also want a native way to batch the data (e.g. `tf.train.batch`). Is there any way to turn a tensorflow object into a numpy array?